# Sort mongod results with javascript/nodejs method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, methods

I am using nodejs with the [matador](https://github.com/Obvious/matador) mvc framework.#

I have this method to query monogodb

```
  .methods({
        getPopular: function(popular) {
          shows.find({date: '2012-07-01'}, popular);
      }
  });
};
```

This works fine. My problem is I don't know how sort the results.

I have tried

```
  .methods({
        getPopular: function(popular) {
          shows.find({date: '2012-07-01'}, popular).sort({show : 1});
      }
  });
};
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way sort works is by sending the key to sort by, and either descending or ascending (-1 or 1)

So using your example to sort by show in a descending matter, you would do the following:

```
.methods({
        getPopular: function(popular) {
          shows.find({date: '2012-07-01'}, popular).sort({show : -1});
      }
  });
```

Mongo documentation explains a bit better:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to include the `sort` keyword in the query options in the Node.js driver.

```
.methods({
    getPopular: function(popular) {
        shows.find({date: '2012-07-01'},{sort:[['show','desc']]}, popular);
    }
});
```

There is a double array (`[['show','desc']]`) because `sort` takes an array of sorting preferences as explained [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#sorting). If you want ascending order, you should use `asc` instead.